# How can I override the php.ini value of max_execution_time at runtime?

Tags: php

I don't have acess to `php.ini` in my server. I want to change the maximum execution time so that my script can runs for more than 30 seconds.

is there any way i can do that on the start of my script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `ini_set`

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  // this will set max_execution time for 300 seconds
```

write this line at start of your code in php file.

**OR**

use this by  **Hanky Panky ㇱ**

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

Comment: You can also use `set_time_limit(300);` to provide an execution time limit for your current script